# Error while execute db to server

Tags: sql-server

Have tried for hours to execute my db to my server, but keeps getting the same error.

What I did first what on my local dbd i did go to tasks -> generate scripts where I under scripts options chose schema and data. After the script was generated, I logged in to my hosts server, where i dragged the database in to my SQL Server Management Studio. Then I removed all the following text:

[Gist with text](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c079a70cfbd5da4300e10dce0dbce04)

and replaced the `USE [aspnet-Billigcsgosalgssite-20170731103725]` with

```
USE sql6003.smarterasp.net
```

After that I did the execute, and got the following error code:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Database 'sql6003' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 223
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I really don't know what to do anymore, and would be happy for some help!

Comment: What is unclear about "Database 'sql6003' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."? You need to create the database first before you can import data to it.

Comment: What happens if you run `select * from sys.databases`?

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to create database on your local machine

```
create database sql6003
```

After this run the script that you have taken from different server